# OSB operation1 in Service1 to also call operation2 in Service2

Tags: osb, operations

I am new on OSB. 
1) I have a Service S1 with two methods say : AsyncQueryAccount, SyncQueryAccount . AsyncQueryAccount has input parameters id, name . SyncQueryAccount has input parameters id,name,addToQueue .

2) I have a Service S2 with one method say : AsyncQueryAccount. This has input parameters id,name .

My Objective is to call S1, S2 both upon request being made to the Proxy.
If operation is AsyncQueryAccount then it should call subsequent method in S1, S2.
If operation is SyncQueryAccount then it should call AsyncQueryAccount removing addToQueue in S2 and SyncQueryAccount in S1.

To achieve this I tried following
Proxy --> Route to S1 
and as part of Route to S1 --> Added a Service Callout to S2 with details saying:
If $operation = 'SyncQueryAccount' or $operation = 'AsyncQueryAccount' then invoke AsyncQueryAccount in S2.

This works fine when AsyncQueryAccount is called, but fails when SyncQueryAccount is called.

How do we make sure that when SyncQueryAccount is called, then AsyncQueryAccount is called in S2 as well.

I get error saying:
A system error has occurred at 'RouteNode1'.  Reason: 'OSB Service Callout action received SOAP Fault response'.  Please contact an ESB system administrator

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your problem,I think flow should be like as below

Proxy --> callout S2 --> if $operation = 'SyncQueryAccount' then callout SycnQueryAccount specific service(please use Xquery for transformation if required) or callout AsyncQueryAccount specific service.

Please try to assign request payload into different variables because I suspect that your request body is getting changed once you recieve response from First service.